# Why am I getting \xc2 when I convert int to character using chr()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In `python 2`, when I use `chr(143)` I get `\x8f`.

But when I do the same thing in `python 3`, `chr(143).encode()`produces `\xc2\x8f`.

Is there a way for me to just get `\x8f` in `python 3`?
Why am I getting `\xc2` in the front?

Comment: Have you tried different encodings (a parameters to `.encode()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using a different encoding, as they produce different results. The default is `utf-8`.

I tried this (using `python 3`):

```
>>> chr(143).encode('latin')
b'\x8f'
>>> chr(143).encode('utf-8')
b'\xc2\x8f'
>>> chr(143).encode('utf-16')
b'\xff\xfe\x8f\x00'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`int.to_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```
>>> (143).to_bytes(1, 'big')
b'\x8f'
>>>
```

Comment: So if i understand this correctly, 'big' sets the most significant byte to the beginning of the order. Will \xc2 always be smaller byte?

Comment: There's only 1 byte here so it really doesn't matter.